# Hours and minutes as labels in Altair plot spanning more than one day

Tags: python, time-series, data-visualization, vega-lite, altair

I'm trying to create in Altair a Vega-Lite specification of a plot of a time series whose time range spans a few days. Since in my case, it will be clear which day is which, I want to reduce noise in my axis labels by letting labels be of the form `'%H:%M'`, even if this causes labels to be non-distinct.

Here's some example data; my actual data has a five minute resolution, but I imagine that won't matter too much here:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create data spanning 30 hours, or just over one full day
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=30, freq='H'),
                   'data': np.arange(30)**.5})
```

By using the otherwise trivial `yearmonthdatehoursminutes` transform, I get the following:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(x='yearmonthdatehoursminutes(time):T', 
y='data:Q')
```

[image]

Now, my goal is to get rid of the dates in the labels on the horizontal axis, so they become something like `['00:00', '03:00', ..., '21:00', '00:00', '03:00']`, or whatever spacing works best.

The naive approach of just using `hoursminutes` as a transform won't work, as that bins the actual data:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(x='hoursminutes(time):T', y='data:Q')
```

[image]

So, is there a declarative way of doing this? Ultimately, the visualization will be making use of selections to define the horizontal axis limits, so specifying the labels explicitly using `Axis` does not seem appealing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on @fuglede's answer, there are two distinct concepts at play with dates and times in Altair.

**Time formats** let you specify how times are displayed on an axis; they look like this:

```
chart.encode(
    x=alt.X('time:T', axis=alt.Axis(format='%H:%M'))
)
```

Altair uses format codes from [d3-time-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format).

**Time units** let you specify how data will be grouped, and they also adjust the default time format to match. They look something like this:

```
chart.encode(
    x=alt.X('time:T', timeUnit='hoursminutes')
)
```

or via the shorthand:

```
chart.encode(
    x='hoursminutes(time):T'
)
```

Available time units are listed [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/timeunit.html#timeunit-transform).

If you want to adjust axis formats only, use time formats. If you want to group based on timespans (i.e. group data by year, by month, by hour, etc.) then use a time unit. Examples of this appear in the Altair documentation, e.g. the [Seattle Weather Heatmap](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/weather_heatmap.html) in Altair's example gallery.

Answer (score 3):

This can actually easily be achieved by specifying `format` in `Axis`:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(x=alt.X('time:T', axis=alt.Axis(format='%H:%M')), y='data:Q')
```

[image]